# NodeJS, Asynchronous exceptions are uncatchable

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, event-loop

I read a very informative [blog (by PANU PITKÄMÄKI)](https://bytearcher.com/articles/why-asynchronous-exceptions-are-uncatchable/) post about why asynchronous exceptions are untracable in NodeJS. It stated that in NodeJS ansynchronous exceptions are untracable because the `catch` block simply doesn't exist in the stack of the event loop. For example:

```
 try {
     setImmediate(() => {
        throw new Error();
     });
 } catch (e) {
     // catch error.. doesn't work
 }
```

I also read the following in the book "NodeJS design patterns:

> Throwing inside an asynchronous callback will cause the exception to jump up the event loop and never be propagated to the next callback. In NodeJS this is an unrecoverable state and causes application to shut down.

### Question:

From the book I get the impression that the event loop has a seperate stack and thus a seperate thread, is this true?

Comment: There's a single thread in Node. The thing you're describing isn't specific to Node but to JS in general. The error doesn't occur at the moment when `try {...}` block is evaluated, if this explanation is more intuitive to you.

Comment: The error occurs in the event loop right?

Comment: Error does not occur in Event-loop rather its just propagated to the event loop as setImmediate is async function which seats in event loop.

Comment: The exception is propagated to event loop, as it was mentioned. FWIW, such exceptions can be handled with https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception .

Comment: @WillemvanderVeen *All* JS code runs in the event loop, so *every* error occurs in the event loop.

Comment: So the event loop is still ticking even when synchronous code is executed? Then after the synchronous code is executed the event loop starts putting items from the event queue on the stack?